# Complicated If VBA for the pro´s

Tags: vba, excel

I have 3 documents

what I need to do (which has to be done with VBA excel because it´s part of a much larger macro) is look at column A in document A and for each instance where there is a match in document B column A I need to check if the value in column B of both documents is = "rf" if it is I need to check if the value in column C of workbook A is > column C.

If all that is true I want to post the value of workbook A column A into workbook C column C in the same cell address.

I have the below code but it is returning an error on the first intersect loop that says "method 'intersect' of object '_global' failed. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
Public Sub RFErrorProof()

Dim input1 As String
Dim input2 As String
Dim rCell As Range
Dim rFound As Range
Dim rNext As Range

Input3 = "ReportCompare.xls"
input1 = Workbooks(Input3).Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A4").Value
input2 = Workbooks(Input3).Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A3").Value

'Loop through column A in doc A
    For Each rCell In Intersect(Workbooks(input2).Worksheets("LocalesMallContratos").UsedRange.Columns(2), Workbooks(input1).Worksheets("LocalesMallContratos").UsedRange.Columns(2)).Cells
    'Skip cells where column B is not RF
    If rCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "RF" Then

        'See if that exists in doc B
        Set rFound = Nothing
        Set rFound = Workbooks(input1).Columns(2).Find(rCell.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)

        'If it's in doc B
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then

            'If column B doc B is RF and doc A is greater than doc B, then write it
            If rFound.Offset(0, 3).Value = "RF" Then
                If rCell.Offset(0, 14).Value > rFound.Offset(0, 14).Value Then
                    Set rNext = Workbooks(Input3).Cells(Workbooks(Input3).Sheets("sheet1").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                    rNext.Value = rCell.Value
                End If
            Else
                'If column B doc B is not RF, write it
                Set rNext = Workbooks(Input3).Cells(Workbooks(Input3).Sheets("sheet1").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                rNext.Value = rCell.Value
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next rCell


End Sub
```

Comment: I suspect it is because you've not done any work of your own. Writing code for people is not done here but helping them is. Especially when your question seems to be already done in similar ways before there would he plenty out there.

Comment: @glh thank you, that makes sense...I omitted my code because it was giving me errors but I will post it asap (I´m at work right now so it might take a moment)

Answer (score 0):

I'm 99% sure this could be simplified in an ENORMOUS way, but I just worked through your logic exactly and came up with this formula (I saw no need to use VBA for this).

Just copy this formula into worksheet C, cell A1 and copy / paste it down:

```
=IF(A!A1=B!A1,IF(A!B1="RF",IF(B!B1<>"RF",A!A1,IF(A!C1>B!C1,A!A1,"")),""),"")
```

Hope this does the trick!

Comment: @Dick Kusleika I just edited my initial post with a derived version of your code and an error I have been getting...any idea how to solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Always test code on a copy of your data.  Make a backup first.

```
Public Sub MakeDocuC()

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim rNext As Range

    'Loop through column A in doc A
    For Each rCell In Intersect(docuA.UsedRange, docuA.Columns(1)).Cells
        'Skip cells where column B is not RF
        If rCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "RF" Then

            'See if that exists in doc B
            Set rFound = Nothing
            Set rFound = docuB.Columns(1).Find(rCell.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)

            'If it's in doc B
            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then

                'If column B doc B is RF and doc A is greater than doc B, then write it
                If rFound.Offset(0, 1).Value = "RF" Then
                    If rCell.Offset(0, 2).Value > rFound.Offset(0, 2).Value Then
                        Set rNext = docuC.Cells(docuC.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        rNext.Value = rCell.Value
                    End If
                Else
                    'If column B doc B is not RF, write it
                    Set rNext = docuC.Cells(docuC.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                    rNext.Value = rCell.Value
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

Comment: I just edited my original post with a modified version of your code but I'm receiving the error detailed above... Any thoughts?

Comment: @ja72 I input the code edits you made and I'm getting the "Method 'intersect' of object'_global' failed" message with regard to the for each rcell loop (the one right after input2 =)... Any ideas of what to do?

Comment: You can't take an Intersect of ranges that aren't on different sheets.  You use Workbooks(input2) and Workbooks(input1) in your Intersect, but those will have to be on different sheets bc there in different workbooks. My Intersect is intersecting column A with the used range - col A is 1 million cells, so I'm limiting it to however many rows you're using - both using docuA.